# Pivot Cell in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, cocoa-touch, swift

I'm  new to IOS programming and I'm trying to create a Pivot Row 
( or cell )  in UITableView ( you know the same as Pivot rows in MS Excell ) , where you would have a main row that sticks to the header or the footer of the table when you scrole the table up and down .

I've tried to search a solution online but could not find any ( perhaps i'm using the wrong terminology ) . I would like to know if UITableView supports such things out of the box or i would have to create a custom table View .

thank you in Advance.

Comment: could you please explain in detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a built in functionality in the sense of what you're thinking. But there might be a work around depending on how many rows you want. If you just want one row, you could override the method:

`- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`

**EDIT:** The table view must have a UITableView style of UITableViewStylePlain for this method to work.

Then you could make something look like this with one view following you down as you scroll the table view.

[image: custom pivot view screenshot]

Otherwise you will have to implement it yourself (which will probably yield better results, and proper customization to your needs).

Comment: thank you very much that  worked just perfect for me , It is worth mentioning that this would only work on a table which has  UITableViewStyle property of the table is set to UITableViewStylePlain